# Importing CSV file to a SQL Server table using SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a requirement where I need to load data into a SQL Server table from a `.CSV` file. The file has around 20 columns, with each of them having the datatype set to `General`.

However, there are a few columns which are of the type `Currency`. I am trying to load the file through a DFT in the SSIS. On loading the file, the SSIS fails at the source task, with the error message showing

> Conversion could not be done as it could lead to a potential loss of data

for one of the amount columns (let's call it `cAmount`) which has amounts in US $. This is failing the SSIS. It failed with the column's Metadata in the SSIS set to `DT_CR(currency)`, `DT_STR`. However, if I change this type to numeric or general in the `.CSV` file, it succeeds without any issue.

Is there something I am not doing correctly or is it just not possible to load currency type into the SQL Server table?

Please let me know if the above query is confusing and if I need to share a screenshot of the same.

Comment: Do you know what values it's breaking on? Do any of the source values have more than four places after the decimal, for example? I believe DT_CR aligns with SQL Server's MONEY types, which store at most one ten thousandth of a unit. Can we see some examples of your data?

Comment: i think u need to do some data conversion before uploading data into sql server

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you amount data contains currency symbols such as ($).
You can't insert currency symbols into a money field (which underlying implementation in sql server is decimal(19,4)).

If you want to insert data with currency symbols then first insert into a temporary table, where "money" field is defined as a varchar. Then update this field and remove all currency symbols.Then write another SQL statement to move the data from the temporary table to the real table.